# Easiest way to setup subversion for a website?

Tags: svn

Let me state that I have am going to sound extremely ignorant right now. I am designer/front-end developer and have no experience with this type of stuff.
I do a lot of work on the side and am currently working on a website that has contracted out all of the programming. Unfortunately, there is constantly a communication gap with the programming company and myself. They are consistently over writing files. At my 9-to-5 I work with a program called "Versions" (It is only for a Mac - I use a PC at home). It helps keep this type of thing from happening. My question is how would I go about setting something like this up? (I currently use an FTP/ FileZilla to upload all of my files to a website.) **AND** would a technological idiot like myself be able to handle it? **OR** Does someone have a less complicated solution to help me out with this.

Let me know if you need any additional info.

Thanks in advance!

DH

Answer (score 1):

Versions is Mac SVN-client.

If you'll create external SVN-repository (accessible from workplace and home): it can be own server or hosted (GoogleCode, SourceForge, Unfuddle, Assembla, Github) solution, reconfigure Versions to use new repo and install SVN-client on Windows (TortoiseSVN is nice, maybe - SmartSVN from Syntevo, crossplatform RapidSVN), you'll be able to use and modify your code from (virtually) any location

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a subversion server and repository in minutes....literally.  Even better...you can do it for free!

A quick google search yielded a guide:

http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/02/setup-a-subversion-server-in-4-minutes/

Otherwise, if you want it to run on you're windows box:

http://willperone.net/Code/svnserver.php

Answer (score 0):

Subversion is fairly easy to set up, and as others have mentioned Versions is merely a client for Subversion so you are already familiar with how it works from an end user perspective.

The thing is you really need to get ALL the contractors and people modifying code to use the repository and thats where you make and push your changes to. Then i would recommend that one person on the team have the responsibility of doing an svn export of the current stable code to the actual development or production server on whatever interval your team needs (1-4 times a day for the dev server maybe).

This way no one is pushing random updates to the server. Everyone works locally and the server gets synced when it needs to. Otherwise youre always going to be manually merging in their uncontrolled modifications and resolving them which is almost as much of a headache as what you are doing now :-)

The quickest cheapest way for non-admin type to do this is to get an account with a hosting company that offers subversion on its account and a configuration interface in their admin panel. [Dreamhost](http://dreamhost.com) does this pretty well, allowing you to configure usernames and passwords and even allows you to hook up Trac (bug/issue/project tracker and wiki) for the repo. And all this will be accessible on the net instead of having to tie something to your local machine.

An even better option (for a few more bucks a month) is [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/pricing). They allow you to choose between Git and Subversion, backup your data, and allow you to configure automated deployments.