# How to setup Svn client for a remote server

Tags: svn, remote-server

i just purchased a shared hosting plan and I want to use subversion on that system. However, I contacted support to **install svn** and they said

> "we do not allow **SVN** repo's on our shared hosting servers. You can
>   use it as a client but not as a repo. You would need to set it up as a
>   SVN client"

I'm new to subversion and I don't know how to set up this for my remote server. (I have also ssh access).

How can I use svn as a client and also how do I use version control in dreamweaver.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to have your svn repository on a separate machine? Can you just host it locally? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There's already a **[good post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146287/easiest-way-to-setup-subversion-for-a-website)** out there on this topic, also another one with links to **[tutorials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169387/installing-and-running-subversion/11169421#11169421)**

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a free account with private SVN repository at [Unfuddle](https://unfuddle.com). This will give you a remote SVN repository (server), which you will need to connect to from your shared hosting "client".

You will then likely want to setup your local development PC with an SVN client, where you will make changes, push them to the remote repository on Unfuddle, then pull them down to the shared hosting account to see the changes appear on your website.

Then study this beginners guide to [using SVN with Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/using_subversion_pt1.html).